# dropdown in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a dropdown function in javascript where only cars show up in a option form.
When users click on "Acura" the models show up, "Vigor", "RSX"...

When the model has been selected the Part Group should come but it dosent show up.
I cannot figure out how the 3rd option should show up.
Thanks
Here is my code

```
getCars.php

<?php

$models = array(
"acura" => array("CL", "EL", "Integra", "Legend", "MDX", "NSX", "RL", "RSX", "SLX", "TL", "TSX", "Vigor"),
"alfa" => array("1750", "Alfetta", "GTV-6", "Romeo 164", "Romeo Milano", "Spyder", "Spyder 1600 Duetto", "Spyder1600", "Veloce 2000")

);

$partgroup = array(
"Accessories" => array("Bed Cover", "Bed Liner", "Bed Rails", "Car Cover", "Converitible Boot Cover", "Jack", 
"Luggage Rack", "Spare Tire Cranks", "Spare Tire Holder", "Tool Kit")

);

//echo "Cars: " . $_GET['cars'];


if(isset($_GET['cars'])) {

    $c = $_GET['cars'];
    $p = $_GET['partGroup'];
        if(isset($models[$c])) {
            for($i = count($models[$c]) -1; $i>=0; $i-- ) {
                echo "<option value='" . $models[$c][$i] . "'>" . $models[$c][$i]. "</option>";
            }
        }

        else if(isset($partgroup[$p])) {
                for($i = count($partgroup[$p]) -1; $i>=0; $i-- ) {
                echo "<option value='" . $partgroup[$p][$i] . "'>" . $partgroup[$p][$i]. "</option>";
            }
            }

}


?>

index.php

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</heady>

<body>

<form name="form1" action="submit.php" method='post'>
Please choose a car model<br/>
<select name="cars" onchange="window.getCars()">
<option disabled>Select Car model </option>
<option value="acura">Acura</option>
<option value="alfa">Alfa</option>
</select>

<br/>



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCars() {
        var xmlhttp;
        try {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

        }catch(e)
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        if(xmlhttp) {
            var form = document['form1'];
            var cars = form['cars'].value;

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/drop/getCars.php?cars="+cars, true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(this.readyState == 4) {
                    var s = document.createElement("select");
                    s.name = "model";
                    s.innerHTML = this.responseText;

                    if(form['model']) {
                        form.replaceChild(s, form['model']);
                    }           


                    else
                        form.insertBefore(s, form['submit']);

                    getpartGroup();
                    //alert(this.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getpartGroup() {
        var xmlhttp;
        try {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

        }catch(e)
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        if(xmlhttp) {
            var form = document['form1'];
            var cars = form['partGroup'].value;

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/drop/getCars.php?partGroup="+partGroup, true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(this.readyState == 4) {
                    var s = document.createElement("select");
                    s.name = "partGroup";
                    s.innerHTML = this.responseText;

                    if(form['partGroup']) {
                        form.replaceChild(s, form['partGroup']);
                    }           


                    else
                        form.insertBefore(s, form['submit']);

                    //alert(this.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
    }

</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont know php but you tricked me with the javascript tag so this may be a dumb question but to me it looks like you are listening for the parts group in the elseif statement? after you found the model in the if statement? I would just think the if loop would close once the first "if" condition was true. i dont know much javascript either though so ignore if Im way off

Comment: @Four_lo: Javascript supports nested conditionals (if statements inside if statements), if that's what you're getting at.  If a conditional inside a conditional is true, the 'inside' statement will loop and then continue through the 'outside' statement like normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler and cleaner to use one of the popular JS frameworks, like jQuery, prototype, backbone, or underscore. These all have support for ajax and updating the DOM, check out some tutorials, it's much-much easier than manually messing around with xmlhttp.

But to the point, you can see where and how the ajax request is going in the chrome dev console (ctrl-shift-i, right click, toggle Log XMLHttpRequests), or firebug console if you are using Firefox. Open the console, select a car, and the ajax request should appear in the console, which you can click for results.

Happy debugging!